# ASA 8.4 multiple ISP route on port?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

ASA-5505, Security Plus license, ASA 8.4, two ISPs. I'd like to send www/https traffic from the inside network out on one ISP interface and everything else on the other. I'm not looking for using it as a backup and I know if one goes down I would lose that range of access. I've seen this done on the other software versions using NAT but am struggling to pull this off on 8.4. Is this even possible anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASA does not support policy based routing (PBR) that you would need in order to route http/https traffic to one ISP and everything else to the other. You would need a router to do this.